Why is my Grading not working if the there are only two scores?
Im writing a grading report system in VBA excel. Im trying to grade one, or two or three papers.
But my code only works if all the three papers are entered. But some subjects have only two, and some teachers manage to do only one paper. Can someone help me read through my code and give me alternatives. Thanks in advance
 Sub gradeLuganda()
 Dim grades As Variant
 Dim grade As String
 Dim containsNine As Boolean Dim countEights As Integer Dim validGrades() As Variant Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

'Initialize an array to hold non-empty grades
ReDim validGrades(0 To 2) As Variant
j = 0

' Populate validGrades with non-empty values from G29, G30, G31
If Not IsEmpty(Range("G29").Value) Then
    validGrades(j) = Range("G29").Value
    j = j + 1
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Range("G30").Value) Then
    validGrades(j) = Range("G30").Value
    j = j + 1
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Range("G31").Value) Then
    validGrades(j) = Range("G31").Value
    j = j + 1
End If

' If there are no valid grades, exit the subroutine
If j = 0 Then
    Range("H29").Value = ""
    Exit Sub
End If

' Resize the validGrades array to the correct number of valid entries
ReDim Preserve validGrades(0 To j - 1)

' Initialize the counts
containsNine = False
countEights = 0

' Check the validGrades array
For i = LBound(validGrades) To UBound(validGrades)
    If validGrades(i) = 9 Then
        containsNine = True
    ElseIf validGrades(i) = 8 Then
        countEights = countEights + 1
    End If
Next i

' Debugging information to see what is being evaluated
Debug.Print "Valid Grades: "; Join(validGrades, ", ")
Debug.Print "Contains Nine: "; containsNine
Debug.Print "Count of Eights: "; countEights

' Determine the grade based on the conditions
Select Case True
    ' Condition for Grade F if any grade is 9 or two or more grades are 8
    Case containsNine Or countEights >= 2
        grade = "F"
    
    ' Handling case for one grade only
    Case j = 1
        Select Case validGrades(0)
            Case 1 To 3
                grade = "B"
            Case 4
                grade = "C"
            Case 5
                grade = "D"
            Case 6 To 7
                grade = "E"
            Case 8
                grade = "O"
            Case 9
                grade = "F"
        End Select
    
    ' Handling case for two grades only
    Case j = 2
        Select Case True
            Case validGrades(0) <= 3 And validGrades(1) <= 3
                grade = "B"
            Case validGrades(0) <= 4 And validGrades(1) <= 4
                grade = "C"
            Case validGrades(0) <= 5 And validGrades(1) <= 5
                grade = "D"
            Case validGrades(0) <= 7 And validGrades(1) <= 7
                grade = "E"
            Case Else
                grade = "F"
        End Select
    
    ' Specific condition for three grades (original logic)
    Case j = 3
        Select Case True
            Case validGrades(0) <= 3 And validGrades(1) <= 3 And validGrades(2) <= 3
                grade = "A"
            
            Case (validGrades(0) <= 4 And validGrades(1) <= 3 And validGrades(2) <= 3) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 3 And validGrades(1) <= 4 And validGrades(2) <= 3) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 3 And validGrades(1) <= 3 And validGrades(2) <= 4)
                grade = "B"
            
            Case (validGrades(0) <= 5 And validGrades(1) <= 4 And validGrades(2) <= 4) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 4 And validGrades(1) <= 5 And validGrades(2) <= 4) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 4 And validGrades(1) <= 4 And validGrades(2) <= 5)
                grade = "C"
            
            Case (validGrades(0) <= 6 And validGrades(1) <= 5 And validGrades(2) <= 5) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 5 And validGrades(1) <= 6 And validGrades(2) <= 5) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 5 And validGrades(1) <= 5 And validGrades(2) <= 6)
                grade = "D"
            
            Case validGrades(0) <= 7 And validGrades(1) <= 7 And validGrades(2) <= 7
                grade = "E"
            
            Case Else
                grade = "F"
        End Select
    
    ' Default case for when other conditions are not met
    Case Else
        grade = "F"
End Select

' Output the grade to the specified cell
Range("H29").Value = grade

End Sub

I did some research and got the solution, which perfectly did what i wanted.
Select Case True
' Grade F if any grade is 9 or two or more grades are 8
Case containsNine Or countEights >= 2
grade = "F"
Debug.Print "Selected Grade: F (Condition: containsNine Or countEights >= 2)"
    ' Handle cases for one grade only
    Case numGrades = 1
        Select Case validGrades(0)
            Case 1 To 3
                grade = "B"
            Case 4
                grade = "C"
            Case 5
                grade = "D"
            Case 6 To 7
                grade = "E"
            Case 8
                grade = "O"
            Case 9
                grade = "F"
        End Select
        Debug.Print "Selected Grade: " & grade & " (Single Grade)"
    
    ' Handle cases for two grades
    Case numGrades = 2
        Select Case True
            Case validGrades(0) <= 2 And validGrades(1) <= 2
                grade = "A"
            Case validGrades(0) <= 3 And validGrades(1) <= 3
                grade = "B"
            Case validGrades(0) <= 4 And validGrades(1) <= 4
                grade = "C"
             Case validGrades(0) <= 5 And validGrades(1) <= 5
                grade = "D"
            Case validGrades(0) <= 6 And validGrades(1) <= 6
                grade = "E"
            Case validGrades(0) <= 7 And validGrades(1) <= 7
                grade = "O"
            Case Else
                grade = "F"
        End Select
        Debug.Print "Selected Grade: " & grade & " (Two Grades)"
    
    ' Handle the original three grades logic
    Case numGrades = 3
        Select Case True
            Case validGrades(0) <= 3 And validGrades(1) <= 3 And validGrades(2) <= 3
                grade = "A"
            Case (validGrades(0) <= 4 And validGrades(1) <= 3 And validGrades(2) <= 3) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 3 And validGrades(1) <= 4 And validGrades(2) <= 3) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 3 And validGrades(1) <= 3 And validGrades(2) <= 4)
                grade = "B"
            Case (validGrades(0) <= 5 And validGrades(1) <= 4 And validGrades(2) <= 4) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 4 And validGrades(1) <= 5 And validGrades(2) <= 4) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 4 And validGrades(1) <= 4 And validGrades(2) <= 5)
                grade = "C"
            Case (validGrades(0) <= 6 And validGrades(1) <= 5 And validGrades(2) <= 5) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 5 And validGrades(1) <= 6 And validGrades(2) <= 5) Or _
                 (validGrades(0) <= 5 And validGrades(1) <= 5 And validGrades(2) <= 6)
                grade = "D"
            Case validGrades(0) <= 7 And validGrades(1) <= 7 And validGrades(2) <= 7
                grade = "E"
            Case Else
                grade = "F"
        End Select

